# Bootstrap link changing my css code

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When I add bootstrap on my html link it changes some of my css code.

Pre-bootstrap:

[image: Pre-bootstrap image]

After-bootstrap:

[image: After-bootstrap image]

Bootstrap link: 
Css code changed:

```
#bannerRodap{
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;    
    width: 100%;
    height:80px;
    top: 88%;
}
#bannerRodap p{
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Helvetica',sans-serif;
    font-size:0.8em; 
}
```

And besides that, bootstrap also added this little blue thing under my flex-box container.

Comment: what do you mean by "adding" bootstrap to your link?

Comment: Try to load first bootstrap and then your own css-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the CSS change you experience is bound to happen, it is one of the **typical  disadvantages of using Bootstrap**. Like the name itself suggests the framework "Bootstrap" makes its complete CSS available to your entire project. Real problem is the immense code the `bootstrap.css` contains even though the programmer doesn't even need most of it(more than 3000 lines). I have taken a very small snippet from the file(`bootstrap.css`) to explain:

```
a {
  color: #337ab7;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #23527c;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

This means all the anchor tag(`<a>`) in your project would have the color `#337ab7` by default UNLESS you override this style to what you need in your own stylesheet. The real problem arises when you see other elements in your project changing its behaviour according to the bootstrap CSS but you really didn't want them to - In this case you need to override the styles coming from `bootstrap.css` **just say in a way to cancel out the bootstrap styles you need to write your own unnecessary styles to make it look normal**.

That's the reason when you ask most of the experienced UI devs about bootstrap they would just go ... ** *yuck* **

- Your own stylesheet starts to get really messy.
- HTML gets messy especially when you start using the grid structure of bootstrap
- Huge unwanted code(from BS CSS/JS) lies in your project even though you will never ever need all of them.

Even the order of the stylesheets included hardly makes any difference. In your case use the Dev Inspector to see whats causing the blue thing(probably a shadow from boostrap) to appear & remove that by overriding the styles in your own stylesheet(in this case, your stylesheet should be included after the bootstrap.css)

> **Imo, bootstrap should be used mostly by those who need bootstrap to do everything about the look & feel of their project with very little customisation to do on their own. If you have heavy customisation of your own then might as well write you own CSS from the scratch without including BS.**